# Option Handling in WEKA

Tags: java, filter, weka

I am creating my own filter in WEKA and would like to know if its possible to add an option handler that is accessible via the WEKA explorer (GUI). From what I have read, it only seems possible to add an option handler that is used via the command line. If it can be achieved, some sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the result, but you could try these steps to access your filter via the WEKA GUI:

1. Go to program files and find weka folder.
2. Find and unzip weka.jar and weka-src.jar.
3. Open the unzipped folders and look for the folder
   named "filters" in both of them. Add your filter's .java and .class
   files there and zip the folders again.
4. Keep a backup of the old weka.jar and weka-src.jar and rename the new zipped folders to weka.jar and weka-src.jar.
5. Run weka again to see if your filter exists!

Comment: You have misunderstood my question. I already have access to my filter via the GUI. I would like to add an option handler for the filter which would be accessible via the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about filters specifically, but if you want to support options in the UI, your class has to have java beans-style methods, e.g., `public String getOption1()` and `public void setOption1(String newValue)`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to implement 'option handler' interfaces in your filter code in order to get the options displayed in GUI. Look at other filters' code to get some ideas.